# question regarding count function

Tags: sql-server, count

I have a table with states and counties.
When I run my count looking for counties, it only returns one column
I would like to output the state for the corresponding county:

```
SELECT county,  
       count(*) AS count
FROM  [AUTOSTEVEKMASTER].[dbo].[M23]
WHERE state is not null
GROUP BY county order by count desc
```

It returns

[image]

I would like the corresponding state in the next column..thank you so much in advance

Steve( Arizona, Florda, Illinois above for example)

Comment: Please do not use images , text only. Add proper data example and expected result, there is no `corresponding state` in the given example. I'm guessing you need to add something like  [STRING_AGG(state , ',') AS state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver16) in your select clause

Comment: I'd love to know how a city can be in a `null` state anyway. Do they pay tax there?

Comment: @Charlieface - Washington, D.C is not in any State

Comment: @MartinSmith Wouldn't call that a `null` state, it's in the District of Columbia which has a special legal status https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/District_of_Columbia_home_rule

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `State` to the `GROUP BY` and your projected columns to get the parent state for each county (e.g. "Florida" for Miami Dade).

```
SELECT state,
       county,
       count(*) AS count
FROM   [AUTOSTEVEKMASTER].[dbo].[M23]
WHERE  state IS NOT NULL
GROUP  BY state,
          county
ORDER  BY count DESC
```

Your current query will put different counties from different states in the same group if they happen to share a name which is very unlikely to be what you want anyway.

Comment: Thank you soooo much.  This is so awesome !!!